# Includes no Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Boa tarde,

Estou com um problema para usar o Entity Framework Core, quando vou fazer uma consulta com includes como abaixo:

```
var protocolos = _protocoloService.Search(p => p.Active == true,
       p => p.Include(l => l.Local)
       , tracking: false).ToList();
```

O json retornado por esse codigo é de aproximadamente 80mb.
fiz um teste utilizando o seguinte código:

```
 var protocolos = _protocoloService.Search(p => p.Active == true, tracking: false).ToList();

 foreach(Protocolo p in protocolos)
 {
       Local local = _localService.GetById(p.ID_Local).Result;
       p.Local = local;
 }
```

O json retornado tem apenas 500kb agora. 
Obs: Estou utilizando o AsNoTracking.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de oque pode ser?
Obrigado

Comment: Provavelmente é dependência circular.

Comment: {
 opts.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.None;
 opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new LowercaseContractResolver();
  opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
 opts.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
}

Essa é as configuraçoes do json que estou usando

Comment: Por acaso o seu GetById não é assíncrono? Você precisa adicionar o await, senão a API vai responder antes que todas as consultas sejam realizadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu segundo código usa o Result, então você deve estar utilizando uma Task de retorno. Como ela trabalha de forma assíncrona, sua API está retornando antes que todas as consultas e o binds do objeto sejam concluídos. Tente adicionar o operador AWAIT para que a thread seja bloqueada e possa retornar o JSON corretamente no retorno da chamada:

```
 var protocolos = _protocoloService.Search(p => p.Active == true, tracking: false).ToList();

 foreach(Protocolo p in protocolos)
 {
       Local local = await _localService.GetById(p.ID_Local);
       p.Local = local;
 }
```

O primeiro código funciona, porque o ToList() não é assincrôno e ele está sobre o scopo do Include.